# Portainer - how to add local path to a volume in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes, portainer

I'm trying to do a basic configuration with **Portainer** but I can't get my volumes to connect properly. I'm trying a relatively simple configuration as you can see but I get an error when I try this:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
    
services:
  app:
    image: webdevops/apache:alpine
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - "/my/host/absolute/path/data: /var/www"
    networks:
    - frontend
  php:
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    container_name: php
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - "/my/host/absolute/path/storage: /var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - backend
```

Could you give me a hand to make this configuration work which would make me a good little starting point to learn to setup the rest correctly.
All I can find in the documentation is how to link named volumes but I don't see how to link them to a folder on my local computer so I'm not really advanced with this information...

Comment: Are there spaces after the colons in the `volumes:` blocks?  Try deleting those; `/host/path:/container/path` with no whitespace.  You also might be able to simplify this setup by removing unnecessary options like `container_name:` and `networks:`.

Answer (score 0):

## Use *"/var/lib..."*

You need to create a volume and after you can access it by using */var/lib/docker/volumes/myVolume/_data*

If you are on Windows and you use **wsl$** go to your file explorer and use this path : *\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes* to find all your existing volumes. You can past every file you want in your volumes and access it in Portainer.

if you follow this steps, you're exemple should look like:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

services:
  app:
    image: webdevops/apache:alpine
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myAppVolume/_data: /var/www"
    networks:
    - frontend
  php:
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    container_name: php
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myStorageVolume/_data: /var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - backend
```